# Desktop manager has stopped working

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem with a game Blade and Soul. I wrote that message on official forum but I didn't get response:

"Hello, I play on laptop Lenovo G500 specification: Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 8600/8700M, processor: Intel Core i7-3612QM 2.1GHz, 4 GB RAM , Windows 7 64 bit

I have problems like:

1. After launching the game, when Blade and Soul mark disappear and PIN screen should appear, I get error massage : "Desktop manager has stopped working" and I also see information: "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered".
2. Sometimes game turned on without errors and I could play for a moment but after about one hour of playing i got "Desktop manager has stopped working" error but I was able to continue playing. Now I have problem 1) over and over again and I can't play. My AMD drivers are updated. Help!"

I found out that it isn't problem with the game. Once, I used VM Ware and problem with Desktop manager has appeared. When I start a game and Desktop manager failure makes my game disappear, the process Client.exe is still running, taking 1GB of RAM, and it will be running until I will close it manually.

I checked logs of Desktop manager problem and they are so long, sorry for polish version of logs but I think main problems are able to be seen:

Version=1 EventType=BEX64 EventTime=131039338353444337 ReportType=2 Consent=1 UploadTime=131039338374385534 ReportIdentifier=bbcbc367-f788-11e5-b959-0cd29269cd9a IntegratorReportIdentifier=bbcbc366-f788-11e5-b959-0cd29269cd9a Response.BucketId=3151941828 Response.BucketTable=5 Response.type=4 Sig[0].Name=Nazwa aplikacji Sig[0].Value=Dwm.exe Sig[1].Name=Wersja aplikacji Sig[1].Value=6.1.7600.16385 Sig[2].Name=Sygnatura czasowa aplikacji Sig[2].Value=4a5bc541 Sig[3].Name=Nazwa modułu z błędem Sig[3].Value=StackHash_94c5 Sig[4].Name=Wersja modułu z błędem Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0 Sig[5].Name=Sygnatura czasowa modułu z błędem Sig[5].Value=00000000 Sig[6].Name=Przesunięcie wyjątku Sig[6].Value=000000c0000000c0 Sig[7].Name=Kod wyjątku Sig[7].Value=c0000005 Sig[8].Name=Dane wyjątku Sig[8].Value=0000000000000008 DynamicSig[1].Name=Wersja systemu operacyjnego DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3 DynamicSig[2].Name=Identyfikator ustawień regionalnych DynamicSig[2].Value=1045 DynamicSig[22].Name=Dodatkowe informacje 1 DynamicSig[22].Value=94c5 DynamicSig[23].Name=Dodatkowe informacje 2 DynamicSig[23].Value=94c5a633886ceeeadcce73111ba76d8b DynamicSig[24].Name=Dodatkowe informacje 3 DynamicSig[24].Value=bb13 DynamicSig[25].Name=Dodatkowe informacje 4 DynamicSig[25].Value=bb1384b3baf92402ddb2de22bf285d90 UI[2]=C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe UI[3]=Program Menedżer okien pulpitu przestał działać. UI[4]=System Windows może wyszukać rozwiązanie tego problemu w trybie online. UI[5]=Wyszukaj rozwiązanie w trybie online (zalecane) UI[6]=Wyszukaj rozwiązanie później (zalecane) UI[7]=Zamknij UI[8]=Menedżer okien pulpitu — zatrzymano działanie i zamknięto UI[9]=Poprawne działanie aplikacji zostało zatrzymane z powodu problemu. System Windows powiadomi Cię, jeśli będzie dostępne rozwiązanie. UI[10]=Za&mknij LoadedModule[0]=C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\UxTheme.dll LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmredir.dll LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmcore.dll LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\d3d10_1.dll LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\d3d10_1core.dll LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\dxgi.dll LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\d3d11.dll LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\guard64.dll LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\shlwapi.dll LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\fltlib.dll LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\aticfx64.dll LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\system32\atiuxp64.dll LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\igd10umd64.dll LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\atidxx64.dll LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\uDWM.dll LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1 State[0].Value=1 State[1].Key=DataRequest State[1].Value=iData=1/nDumpFile=//Upload//iCab//64-3fa627fdd7ae4d1894912a5e0c99b68a-13adc505938409b4ea69becab113bf46-5--1143025468-BEX64-6-1-7601-2.cab/nDumpServer=watson.microsoft.com/nResponseServer=watson.microsoft.com/nResponseURL=//dw//GenericFour.asp?iBucket=-1143025468&szCab=3fa627fdd7ae4d1894912a5e0c99b68a.cab&EventType=BEX64&BucketHash=13adc505938409b4ea69becab113bf46&MID=F936E69F-88EC-49D1-9396-18F0307E0012/nMemoryDump=1/nBucket=-1143025468/nBucketTable=5/nResponse=1/n FriendlyEventName=Zatrzymano działanie. ConsentKey=BEX64 AppName=Menedżer okien pulpitu AppPath=C:\Windows\system32\Dwm.exe

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: follow the steps here: http://pastebin.com/4rNhzBdL, create a dump and share the zip dmp file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjuq720kbv3lv5z/dwm.exe.1608.zip?dl=0

Comment: an update? Has AMD released a new driver that fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the dump, the crash is caused by the AMD display drivers:

```
PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  aticfx64.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  8.17.10.1452

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  AMD Inc. Radeon DirectX 11 Driver

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)

APP:  dwm.exe

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

INVALID_POINTER_READ
    Tid    [0x680]
    Frame  [0x00]: aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo

IN_CALL
    Tid    [0x680]
    Frame  [0x00]: aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo
    Failure Bucketing


BUGCHECK_STR:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_IN_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_IN_CALL

STACK_TEXT:  
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation
03 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
04 kernel32!WerpReportFault
05 kernel32!BasepReportFault
06 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter
07 ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
08 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
09 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
0a ntdll!RtlDispatchException
0b ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0c aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo
0d aticfx64!OpenAdapter10_2
0e aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo
0f aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo
10 aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo
11 aticfx64!OpenAdapter10_2
12 aticfx64!OpenAdapter10_2
13 aticfx64!OpenAdapter10_2
14 aticfx64!OpenAdapter10_2
15 d3d11!CResource<ID3D11Buffer>::CLS::FinalConstruct
16 d3d11!TCLSWrappers<CBuffer>::CLSFinalConstructFn
17 d3d11!CLayeredObjectWithCLS<CBuffer>::CreateInstance
18 d3d11!CDevice::CreateLayeredChild
19 d3d11!CBridgeImpl<ID3D11LayeredDevice,ID3D11LayeredDevice,CLayeredObject<CDevice> >::CreateLayeredChild
1a d3d11!CD3D11LayeredChild<ID3D11DeviceChild,NDXGI::CDevice,64>::FinalConstruct
1b d3d11!NDXGI::CDeviceChild<IDXGIResource1>::FinalConstruct
1c d3d11!CLayeredObject<NDXGI::CResource>::CreateInstance
1d d3d11!NDXGI::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild
1e d3d11!CBridgeImpl<ID3D11LayeredDevice,ID3D11LayeredDevice,CLayeredObject<NDXGI::CDevice> >::CreateLayeredChild
1f d3d11!NOutermost::CDeviceChild::FinalConstruct
20 d3d11!CUseCountedObject<NOutermost::CDeviceChild>::CreateInstance
21 d3d11!NOutermost::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild
22 d3d11!CDevice::CreateBuffer_Worker
23 d3d11!CDevice::ID3D10Device1_CreateBuffer_
24 dwmcore!CHwRenderStateManager::Init
25 dwmcore!CHwRenderStateManager::Create
26 dwmcore!CD3DRenderState::Init
27 dwmcore!CD3DDeviceLevel1::Init
28 dwmcore!CD3DDeviceLevel1::Create
29 dwmcore!CD3DDeviceManager::CreateNewDevice
2a dwmcore!CD3DDeviceManager::GetD3DDeviceCreationParams
2b dwmcore!CHwDisplayRenderTarget::Create
2c dwmcore!CDesktopRenderTarget::Init
2d dwmcore!CDesktopRenderTarget::Create
2e dwmcore!CMILFactory::CreateDesktopRenderTarget
2f dwmcore!CSlaveHWndRenderTarget::EnsureRenderTargetInternal
30 dwmcore!CSlaveHWndRenderTarget::CheckDeviceState
31 dwmcore!CRenderTargetManager::CheckDeviceState
32 dwmcore!CComposition::CheckDeviceState
33 dwmcore!CComposition::ProcessComposition
34 dwmcore!CComposition::Compose
35 dwmcore!CPartitionVerticalBlankScheduler::Render
36 dwmcore!CPartitionVerticalBlankScheduler::ProcessFrame
37 dwmcore!CPartitionVerticalBlankScheduler::Run
38 dwmcore!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain
39 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
3a ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


BUCKET_ID:  X64_INVALID_POINTER_READ_IN_CALL_aticfx64!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo+137d3

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  aticfx64.dll!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_IN_CALL_c0000005_aticfx64.dll!AmdQueryPowerXpressDeviceInfo

0:003> lmvm aticfx64
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
000007fe`fa560000 000007fe`fa6d6000   aticfx64   (export symbols)       aticfx64.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: aticfx64.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\aticfx64.dll
    Image name: aticfx64.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Mar 21 15:12:35 2016 (56F00153)
    CheckSum:         0017FA46
    ImageSize:        00176000
    File version:     8.17.10.1452
    Product version:  8.17.10.1452
    File flags:       0 (Mask 0)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04e4
    CompanyName:      Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
    ProductName:      AMD Inc. Radeon DirectX 11 Driver
    InternalName:     aticfx64.dll
    OriginalFilename: aticfx64.dll
    ProductVersion:   8.17.10.1452
    FileVersion:      8.17.10.1452
    PrivateBuild:     Built by swtools on CNABDE05 on 03/21/16 at 10:12
    SpecialBuild:     DevStudio Build
    FileDescription:  aticfx64.dll
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (C) 1998-2012 AMD Inc.
    LegalTrademarks:  Radeon (TM) is a Trademark of AMD Inc.
```

I also got such crashes if I only updated the AMD drivers. I always had to uninstall the AMD and Intel HD drivers, install the latest Intel HD drivers and next the AMD graphic card drivers.

Comment: And what about version of AMD graphic card drivers? The latest or some previous version? If some previous,I would be grateful for specific version number.

Comment: I have uninstalled Intel HD and AMD drivers. I have installed first the latest Intel HD drivers and then th latest version of AMD and problem has changed. Now when I want to start the game, Client disappear but there is no message that Display manager has stopped  working. Now there is only information about AMD driver which stopped working and has recovered.

Comment: remove both again, install the Intel HD and try the 16.4.1 hotfix driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-Software-Crimson-Edition-16.4.1.aspx

Comment: It didn't help ;/ Sometimes the game turns on and then i can play normally but otherwise blackscreen of the game appears then it disappears and message of drivers  "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" shows.

Comment: report the issues to AMD in their forums, so that they can fix it

Comment: I will try reinstall Windows and if it doesn't help I will report problem to AMD. Thx for trying to help!